# Maintenance tasks on Azure SQL Managed instance

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, maintenance-plan

I have 4 SQL managed instances and have some custom task defined on SQL Managment Studio. On azure I found that the managed instance have a Maintenance Window:
[image]

My question is.. What kind of tasks are performed in the Azure maintenance window?

I only found this about azure maintenance window https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/maintenance-window?view=azuresql, but i want to know list of operations that azure does during this maintenance...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maintenance window feature provides you with the ability to onboard Azure SQL resource to prescheduled time blocks outside of business hours.

As per this [Official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/maintenance-window-faq?view=azuresql#what-types-of-updates-are-typically-performed-during-a-maintenance-window)

> These are types of the updates performed during a maintenance window.
>
> - Hardware
> - Firmware
> - Operating system
> - Satellite software components
> - SQL Engine

They're typically combined into a single batch to minimize the incidence of maintenance events.

These are some of the approaches and operations involved in the maintenance window:

- Hot patching or dynamic patching to apply updates without restarting the services.
- Maintaining a quorum of database replicas for the high-availability of Azure database infrastructure.
- Uses Automatic Scheduling to prevent updates during region’s peak business hours.
- Analysing database workload patterns to chose the best time for failover resources.

**SOURCES:**
https://www.sqlshack.com/azure-sql-database-maintenance-window/ by **Rajendra Gupta**.

[Maintenance Window FAQ - Azure SQL | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/maintenance-window-faq?view=azuresql)